# Acheter qqch à/de/pour qqn

Tags: prépositions

J'ai de la difficulté à saisir la différence entre « acheter qqch à/de/pour qqn », même après avoir lu deux discussions sur WordReference sur le sujet [[1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/acheter-qqch-de-%C3%A0-qqn.1099884/), [2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-acheter-qqch-%C3%A0-pour-de-qqn.1330547/)].

Prenons l'exemple de « J'achète un livre à/de/pour mon ami. »

De ce que j'ai compris de ces discussions :

- **de** : J'achète un livre qui appartenait à mon ami mais il n'est pas forcément le vendeur.
- **à** : Ceci peut signifier deux choses selon le contexte :

  1. Mon ami me vend un livre mais il n'est pas forcément le propriétaire.
  2. J'achète un livre avec l'intention de le donner à mon ami.
- **pour** : Ceci peut signifier deux choses selon le contexte :

  1. J'achète un livre avec l'intention de le donner à mon ami.
  2. J'achète un livre au nom de mon ami

Est-ce que j'ai bien saisi les différences? Y a-t-il d'autres nuances que j'ai manquées?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, les différences sont bien celles-là.

On pourrait ajouter comme variante de la première phrase (… un livre de mon ami) :

> J'achète un livre dont l'auteur est mon ami.