# Acheter à, to mean both "from" and "for"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I understand from this post:

[Acheter qqch à/de/pour qqn](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25504/acheter-qqch-%C3%A0-de-pour-qqn)

that "acheter qqch à qqun" could mean "to buy something for someone", or "to buy something from someone", and that only context clarify the ambiguity.

How do I say the following sentence in French, then, which requires both "for" and "from"?

"Can you buy a birthday cake *for* my nephew *from* that fancy bakery we went to last year?"

Answer (score 1):

I would translate the following sentence:

> Can you buy a birthday cake **for** my nephew **from** that fancy bakery we went to last year?

In french this way:

> Pouvez-vous acheter un gâteau d'anniversaire **pour** mon neveu, **à** cette
>   boulangerie de luxe où nous sommes allés l'année dernière?

---

Q:Can I have more explanations about why did you use "à" in the last sentence ?
A: Yes, I'll try:

**à** is a french préposition used here in order to describe a **destination**;

> **FR:** Où allons nous? *Nous allons à Paris.*
>   **EN:** Where are we going? *We're going to Paris.*
>
> **FR:** Où allons nous pour acheter le gâteau d'anniversaire? *Nous allons à cette
>   boulangerie de luxe où nous sommes allés l'année dernière.*
>    **EN:**   Where are we going to buy the birthday cake ?     *We're going to that fancy bakery we went to last year.*

Comment: 1) So if I say "I'm going to buy a birthday cake for my nephew, from Paul", I can still use "à", even though "Paul" is not a destination? 2) With "Je vais acheter un gâteau à mon neveu", could this indeed mean both "I'm going to buy a cake for my nephew" and "I'm going to buy a cake from my nephew"? 3) If I mean to say "for my nephew", is there a difference in meaning between "à mon neveu" and "pour mon neveu"?

Answer (score 1):

The [question you linked](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25504/acheter-qqch-%C3%A0-de-pour-qqn) already tells a way to disambiguate the intended meaning when *à* is followed by a person:

J'achète un livre à/pour mon ami.

- **à** : Ceci peut signifier deux choses selon le contexte :

1. ...
2. **J'achète un livre avec l'intention de le donner à mon ami.**

- **pour** : Ceci peut signifier deux choses selon le contexte :

1. **J'achète un livre avec l'intention de le donner à mon ami.**
2. ...

Note that the same issue does happen with *lui*:

> À propos de mon ami, est-ce que tu peux **lui** acheter un gâteau d'anniversaire.

Here the friend can be either the recipient or the seller.

However, your English sentence is not a good example of this potential issue as you use a different ***à***:

> Can you buy a birthday cake for my nephew **from** that fancy bakery we went to last year?

Here *from* doesn't mean *from someone* but *from some place*. In such case, there is no ambiguity so you might still use ***à*** for both terms:

> *Est-ce que tu peux acheter un gâteau d'anniversaire **à** mon neveu **à** la super pâtisserie où on est allés l'année dernière ?*

In any case, the meaning is very often obvious, even without more context than the sentence itself. e.g.

> *J'ai acheté des chaussures **à** mon fils* (for my son)

> *J'ai acheté une langouste **à** mon poissonnier* (from my fishmonger)

Comment: is it true that your example sentence (with "... un gâteau d'anniversaire à mon neveu à la super pâtisserie") *could* mean (even if it's very unlikely) "Can you buy a cake from my nephew (ie, paying my nephew some money), for the bakery (ie, giving the cake to the bakery)" ?  Or is there in fact zero possibility of this sentence meaning this, because of some reason involving "à + [non-person]" always meaning "from [non-person]"?

Comment: The eventuality for *à la pâtisserie* to mean *for the bakery* is essentially zero. Even when the place is not a commercial one, you won't say *à*. The sentence *j'ai acheté une nouvelle porte d'entrée à la maison* is not idiomatic. There is however a slight possibility for the nephew to work at the bakery and then the cake to be for someone else's birthday: Can you buy a birthday cake from my nephew in that fancy bakery...

Comment: so, "Can you buy a cake for my husband from my nephew in that fancy bakery" could be translated by "Mon neveu est pâtissier. Est-ce que tu peux acheter un gâteau **à** mon mari **à** mon neveu **à** la pâtisserie de luxe"? If so, it interests me that a sentence can use `à` multiple times in the same short sentence.

Comment: No. *À mon mari à mon neveu* is impossible. That would be *est-ce que tu peux acheter un gâteau à mon neveu pour mon mari à la pâtisserie* (which is a little convoluted) or just *est-ce que tu peux lui acheter un gâteau pour mon mari* as you just say *mon neveu est pâtissier*. In either case, you would probably avoid saying *à la pâtisserie de luxe où on est allés* as there is no evidence he is working in it.

Comment: (I hope it's okay that I continue asking about this question, a year later..). I want to make sure I understand correctly: *J'achète un gâteau à mon mari* is acceptable, and *J'achète un gâteau à la boulangère amicale* is acceptable; but *J'achète un gâteau à mon mari à la boulangère amicale* is not acceptable. Is it not acceptable only because it sounds ugly and awkward, or is it not acceptable because it is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: No problem with new comments whatever the interval of time. *J'achète un gâteau à mon mari à la boulangère amicale* (or better: *à la gentille boulangère*) is grammatically correct. While unlikely to be heard, it can nevertheless be used because there is no real ambiguity.

Comment: 1) So, * "J'achète un gâteau à mon mari à la gentille boulangère."* is OK, but "*J'achète un gâteau à mon mari à mon niveau.*" is usually unacceptable; but it is acceptable if, by context, the person hearing me speak knows that my cousin works at a bakery and so I'm buying a cake for my husband (or, that my husband works at a bakery and so I'm buying a cake for my cousin)? 2) "*J'achète un gâteau pour mon mari à mon niveau.*" should always be OK?

Comment: What is *mon niveau*?

Comment: whoops. *mon niveau* is a careless mistake. i meant to say *mon neveu*, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you understand and explain perfectly well.

In french "acheter à ..." can both mean "buy from" and "buy for", depending on the context, the sentence.